# Print entered values of form fields if form is not valid in django

Tags: python, django

This is my from, I want to display all values entered before submitting this form, if this form is not valid. When i submit this form validation works successfully, but it removes all values from form fields

```
class PromoterRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True, max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'custome-input promote-input', 
        'autocomplete' : 'off',
        'required' : 'required',
        'data-empty-message' : 'Please enter a email.',
        'data-error-message' : 'Please enter a valid email.'
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(required = True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'custome-input promote-input',
        'autocomplete' : 'off',
        'required' : 'required',
        'data-empty-message' : 'Please enter password.'
    }))
    firstname = forms.CharField(required = True, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'custome-input promote-input', 
        'autocomplete' : 'off',
        'required' : 'required',
        'data-empty-message':'Please enter first name.' 
    }))
    lastname = forms.CharField(required = True, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'custome-input promote-input', 
        'autocomplete' : 'off',
        'required' : 'required',
        'data-empty-message':'Please enter last name.' 
    }))
```

View is :-

```
def signup(request):
promoterRegistrationForm = PromoterRegistrationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    promoterRegistrationForm = PromoterRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if promoterRegistrationForm.is_valid():
        #code for saving data
    return render(request, 'home/signup.py', {'promoterRegistrationForm':promoterRegistrationForm})
else:
    promoterRegistrationForm = PromoterRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'home/signup.py', {'promoterRegistrationForm':promoterRegistrationForm})
```

Template is :

```
<form id="promoter-registration-form" action="signup" method="POST">
    {{ promoterRegistrationForm.non_field_errors }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="page-login-outer register-modal-outer">
        <div class="login-div">
            <div class="login-form custom-text-boxs">
            {{ promoterRegistrationForm.email }}
                <label class="custom-text-box">Email*</label>
                {% if promoterRegistrationForm.email.errors %}
                    <ul class="error-ul">
                    {% for error in promoterRegistrationForm.email.errors %}
                        <li style="color:red;">{{ error|escape }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: show us your view also

Comment: please check edit

Comment: This code already does what you want. You must be doing something strange in the template, please post that (and explain why you've given it a .py extension, it's not a Python file).

Comment: If you are not doing anything with your form in your `is_valid()` method, your app should not reset your fields

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have uploaded email field in template, and regarding extension should i change it to html extension ?

Comment: I checked html script in firebug after submitting form, its printing values there but not showing in browser, means problem is with my html style not in django code.